# Declarar un tipo en TypeScript para una libreria

Tags: typescript

en este caso se importa la libreria/modulo (d3js) desde un archivo y se lo pasa por parametro a "chartInfo".
¿Existe algun tipo equivalente a "module" o alguna forma de crearlo?

instancia de datos:

```
let chartInfoData = {
      container: this.container.nativeElement,
      data: dataChart,
      config: this.data.titleConfig,
      meassures: this.data.meassures,
      print: false,
      maskValue: this.utils.formatValue,
      range: this.data.range,
      d3: d3
    }
```

Interface:

```
export interface IChartInfoDataC {
    container: HTMLDivElement;
    data: any;
    config: IConfig;
    meassures: any[];
    print: boolean;
    maskValue: (value: number, format: object) => number;
    range: IRangeChartInfo;
    d3: any;
}
```

Comment: Lo puedes declarar `any`.

Comment: El código debe ir en formato texto y no en imagen. Por favor haz clic en [edit] y cambia lo que haga falta. Saludos

Comment: Por otro lado, `d3.js` tiene una declaración de tipos [aquí](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/d3), para trabajar con Typescript

Comment: Corregido. No tengo idea como es el tema de @types si me darías algún link me seria de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando usas una librería Javascript en un proyecto Typescript, tienes el problema de que los tipos de dicha librería no están declarados en ningún sitio. Para solucionar este problema existe en Typescript los ficheros de declaración: `<nombre_del_fichero>.d.ts`

Estos ficheros no generan código, su función es declarar tipos para librerías de Javascript que quieras usar en Typescript. Por ejemplo, imagina que tienes una librería donde tienes funciones útiles pero no quieres reescribirla para añadir los tipos:

##### `util.js`

```javascript
function shuffle(array) {
  let currentIndex = array.length,  randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle.
  while (currentIndex != 0) {

    // Pick a remaining element.
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex--;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
      array[randomIndex], array[currentIndex]];
  }

  return array;
}
```

Ahora puedes crear una declaración así:

##### util.d.ts

```js
//Usando generics
function shuffle<T>(array : T[]): T[];
```

En el caso de librerías de terceros (como d3js), necesitas obtener este fichero de declaraciones, usando `@types`, que es un enorme repositorio donde las librerías más populares han añadido su fichero de declaraciones (jQuery, Undescore, d3js, etc.):

```
npm install --save @types/d3
```